# How to make this "$ export TFHUB_CACHE_DIR=/my_module_cache" instruction work in windows?

Tags: tensorflow, environment-variables

This is Unix styled command what would be its Windows equivalent? while using setx in place of of $ export following error is found.

```
    SETX  TFHUB_CACHE_DIR=/my_module_cache
    File "<stdin>", line 1
    SETX  TFHUB_CACHE_DIR=/my_module_cache
                    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is TFHUB_CACHE_DIR supposed to be an environment variable?

Comment: This isn't directly relevant to tensorflow.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I don't know where the models are being stored.